# How to use dialogflow sdk in typescript?

Tags: typescript, dialogflow-es, typescript-typings

I'm creating a chatbot app with angular 6 and I want to use the dialogflow sdk. Because the sdk is just for javascript, I also added the typings for dialogflow.

package.json:

```
dependencies: {
    [...]
    "@types/dialogflow": "0.6.3",
    "dialogflow": "0.6.0
}
```

I tried many different imports:

```
import { SessionsClient } from 'dialogflow';
import { SessionsClient, v2 } from 'dialogflow';
import * as dialogflow from 'dialogflow';
import 'dialogflow'
```

But I'm always getting the error

> MODULE_NOT_FOUND

When I try to use it

```
this.dialogflowSessionsClient = new SessionsClient();
this.dialogflowSessionsClient = new v2.SessionsClient();
this.dialogflowSessionsClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient();
```

The IDE can resolve the reference. So, what am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I tried it also in a new angular project and now I have a better error message. Unfortunately, it doesn't help me either.

> ./node_modules/dialogflow/src/v2/agents_client.js
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './agents_client_config' in '/Users/[my-project-path]/node_modules/dialogflow/src/v2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am doing the same thing, there is a front-end JS client library available in this [link](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-javascript-client). All I had to do was use npm to install it and then import it into my Ionic project, but there is very little maintenance so honestly I would suggest using the newer [HttpClient library](https://angular.io/guide/http) or some other good REST library and make the REST calls using the [v2](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest) reference docs.

Google describes how they map REST calls to their gRPC protocol in their http [protobuf](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/api/http.proto), they call it "transcoding".

I know this is a more difficult way than using a client library, but honestly it will be much more worth it than using a library with minimal support (at least until there is a better maintained client library.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Jonathan.
I'm using the library you suggested. It works great, but I need the V2 features like sending custom data.
I also tried to write it for my own. Then I get CORS errors. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52838292/how-to-send-a-request-to-dialogflow-v2-cors-issue?noredirect=1#comment92605252_52838292) 
Did you get them, too?

Comment: Just found out we shouldn't be calling DF directly from the front-end, that explains the CORS issues as well. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/dialogflow/HdQgHv17CYM

This goes for V1 AND V2, I'm now building a backend to redirect the client requests, because apparently we are supposed to use server-to-server auth anyway and the OAuth style is called 'two legged' auth, see this link: https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/which-oauth-flow-to-use

In short, my flow will be:
User -> My backend -> DF -> My backend -> User 

You can E-mail me at jbdoster@gmail.com

Comment: I bristled to use another backend because it increases the latency and seems to be unnecessary. But I now also believe there is no other way. Thanks for your help, @Jonathan!
May you want to add this additional backend hint to your answer?

Comment: Well I ended up using Firebase Functions, and come to find out that's what the Dialogflow In-Line editor is already using. It's all making sense now.

So we write out firebase functions then export them, and the clients (phones and browsers) will call these firebase functions with a URL that firebase functions tells us to use, so the firebase function handles the request from AND response to the client.